# Do 1350 RP skins go on sale?

Tags: league-of-legends

Last patch introduced the Ultimate Tier of skins(one tier higher than legendary skins), and many of the formerly 975 RP skins, such as iBlitzcrank, Soul Reaver Draven, and Full Metal Jayce, have moved up to the 1350 RP standard. Do these 1350 RP semi legendary tier skins ever go on sale?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes. And here is an exerpt from the red post that explains why.
Here is the [link](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3328361) to that post if you wish to read further.

> 1350
>
> - Skins in the 1350 RP tier will feature a new model, textures, splash image, animations, visual effects and sounds. In some cases, these skins will also have processed voice overs.
> - This tier is intended for skins that go above and beyond the quality of 975 RP skins but don't quite reach legendary status.
> - 3 skins from the current 1820 Legendary tier will have their prices lowered to 1350 RP.
>     17 skins from the current 975 RP tier will be moved to the 1350 RP tier.
> - We expect that 7-15% of skins released in 2013 will be 1350 RP, **and they are eligible to be put on sale**.
> - Examples: Blackthorn Morgana, Arcade Sona